# Why isn't there an "acapella" tag?

Tags: discussion

I see a "choir" tag but no "acapella" tag. I'm forming an acapella team in my college and Music.SE seems like the perfect resource to answer all our questions. Is tagging our questions under "choir" enough or should you guys also have an "acapella" tag for questions from people like us?

Thank you. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Once you have enough points you earn a badge to create tags :)

Comment: There is also a "voice" tag.

Answer (score 8):

Tags are generally created once there is sufficient need for them, not for the first post that might use it. So if you begin posting questions which are specific to a Capella and not in the general choir tag, then we can do that.

Please do post questions - we'd like to see them.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [acapella](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acapella) tag as of September 16, 2020. Here is the [info page](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/acapella/info).